# How would I translate this html POST request into python

Tags: python, html

I am having difficulty translating this specific HTML POST request into Python - I am attempting to exploit a security vulnerability on a test server.

```html
director=
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/card/0" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="8000" />
  <input type="hidden" name="username" value="hacker" />
  <input type="submit" value="View my photos" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please elaborate. What do you mean by translating? And what difficulty do you face?

Comment: Sorry, I have never posted a question on here.  I know that a simple python POST request is formatted like
postReq = {"name": "value, etc..}
but I don't know how to set the variable "director" in my request

Comment: But what is it you are trying to do? Send a POST request to a server from Python?

Comment: Technically, I am trying to write regression tests to see if I patched a vulnerability on a django web app - it would be simpler to just modify the defective page.  But yes, I'm trying to send a post request to a server and modify a specific variable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Before you run the code below. Run pip install requests.

```
import requests

response = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json")
print(response)

>>>> Response<200>
```

See more details in the URL below.

https://www.nylas.com/blog/use-python-requests-module-rest-apis/